# AverageRating is null in JSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, query

I am trying to get the rating field from a SharePoint pages library in JavaScript, after using the `get_item('AverageRating')` it's returning null.

My function looks like the following:

```
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');
   var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
   query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl("pages/subfolder");
   query.set_viewXml('<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">\
   <Query>\
   <Where>\
      <Neq>\
    <FieldRef Name="ContentType" />\
    <Value Type="Text">Folder</Value>\
     </Neq>\
   </Where>\
    <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy></Query></View>');


    var listItems = targetList.getItems(query);

    var results = context.loadQuery(listItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(_onSucceed, _Fail);

   function _onSucceed(){

        var html="";

        for(var i = 0; i <results.length; i++){
        html+="<p>"+results[i].get_item("AverageRating")+"</p>";
        }


        $(divSelector).html(html); 

   }

   function _Fail(){
   alert("fail"); 
   }
```

Is there something wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is nothing wrong with your approach, you are getting null values since rating values have **not** been specified.

In case if Ratings fields are not available, the following error usually occurs:

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested

In addition you could also specify explicitly to return Ratings field values as demonstrated below:

```
function getListItems(listTitle,viewSchema,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
   query.set_viewXml(viewSchema);
   var items = list.getItems(query);
   ctx.load(items);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       success(items);
   },error);
}


//Usage
var viewSchema = '<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">\
                     <Query/>\
                     <ViewFields> \
                         <FieldRef Name="AverageRating" /> \
                         <FieldRef Name="RatingCount" /> \
                     </ViewFields> \
                  </View>';

getListItems('Pages',viewSchema,
   function(items)
   {
       for(var i = 0;i < items.get_count();i++) {
           var item = items.get_item(i);
           console.log(item.get_item("AverageRating"));
       }
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```